# Python regex matching with only second capturing group - not using the first capturing group

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've this regex :

```
con = r"(((consignee)\s?(name)?\s?(and)?\s?(address)?)|((name)?\s?(and)?\s?(address)?\s?(of)?\s?(consignee)))"
```

I'm trying to match with the following texts :

```
txt1 = 'NAME AND ADDRESS OF CONSIGNEE :'
txt2 = '    consignee name and address :'
```

I'm using `re.finditer()` like this :

```
match1 = [i.group() for i in re.finditer(con, txt1, re.IGNORECASE)]
match2 = [i.group() for i in re.finditer(con, txt2, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

The result I'm getting is this :

```
>>> match1
['NAME AND ADDRESS OF CONSIGNEE']
>>> match2
['    consignee']
```

My desired output is `['consignee name and address']` for `match2`. Even though I've already added this into regex, why is it not capturing the group?

I've tried re-ordering the regex like this :

```
con = r"(((name)?\s?(and)?\s?(address)?\s?(of)?\s?(consignee))|((consignee)\s?(name)?\s?(and)?\s?(address)?))"
```

But still in this case also, `match2` is always only `['    consignee']`. I've also checked out regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/ah26YG/3/), which is also giving the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The pattern is rather fragile due to lots of subsequent optional patterns that may overlap. `(name)?` is optional, but `(consignee)` is not. Make `(consignee)` optional, or make both obligatory (remove `?` after `(name)`). Probably, the latter is better, see https://regex101.com/r/aelbVu/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `consignee` must be present in the string to match. Thing is `name and address of` might be present before it (if present then match) or `name and address` might be present after it (if present then match). I can't make `consignee` optional or make `name` obligatory.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/7pbqLa/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed some brackets in the pattern and it worked for me. Every part is optional besides consignee.

```
con = r"(consignee\s?(name)?\s?(and)?\s?(address)?|(name)?\s?(and)?\s?(address)?\s?(of)\s?consignee)"
```